# Can I make only a certain portion of a tableview clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add a like button in a tableview but If I click anywhere in the tableview, it immediately goes to the detailsVC. I want to make it so when you click that like button, only that is selected. Is there a way to make it so only the top half of the tableview can be selectable or have interaction enabled, and put the button below? Or is there another way to do this. Is there a workaround or a method I am missing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the UIButton is added correctly to table view cell's .contentView? 
Can you see it? If so it will intercept the touch events and tableview's delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath won't get called (even if there's no handling connected to the button). If you want make the button occupy specific area of the cell you can either:

- Design your cell in Interface Builder and make it a part of Storyboard/Xib
- Do autolayout of the cell programmatically
- Override cell's layoutSubviews and manually setup the frames